# How to Create a Wordpress Homepage Slider with Multiple Queries for Most Recent or Featured Posts from 4 Unique Categories?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I am working on creating a slider for a WordPress site I am building. The slider I am trying to build will have 4 total slides/frames. Each frame will need to display either the most recent post from a unique category or a featured post from a unique category. By this I mean that each of the 4 slides/frames will represent a separate category.

```
Slide/Frame 1 = Most Recent or Featured Post from Category A
Slide/Frame 2 = Most Recent or Featured Post from Category B
Slide/Frame 3 = Most Recent or Featured Post from Category C
Slide/Frame 4 = Most Recent or Featured Post from Category D
```

The layout/design of my slider will have 4 navigation icons/buttons at the top. Each of these icons/buttons will represent one of the categories. These can be used to navigate from slide/frame to slide/frame. Below the icons/buttons will be the Featured Image for the most recent/featured post. Below the Featured Image will be an image that represents the category (an image of the category name). Below that will be the Post Title followed by the Post Date (and possibly Post Excerpt).

LAYOUT:

- Category A Icon/Button - Category B Icon/Button - Category C Icon/Button - Category D Icon/Button
- Featured Image for Most Recent or Featured Post in Category
- Image Representing the Category
- Post Title
- Post Date
- Post Excerpt (maybe)

I believe I'll need to create 4 different queries; one query for each slide/frame in the slider. Can anybody help me figure out how best to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 1):

I would search for a plugin that can do the magic. This one does.. Can pull results from multiple catwgories and is highly configurable.. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/promotion-slider/

Answer (score -1):

I have done this using easing slider lite plugin

It gives option to customize and make changes to the slideshow and add categories,

I have set it up on my website using tutorial below

http://www.bestwebsitesdesigner.com/web-design/tutorial-explaining-how-to-add-slider-in-wordpress-website/#more-1328

Please let me know if this works for you

best of luck

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.  It simply shows you how to add the slider.  Nothing to address the issue the original poster is asking about.