# How to automatically display featured images from blog posts in a slider on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, blogs

So I've looked at this question ([How to Create a Wordpress Homepage Slider with Multiple Queries for Most Recent or Featured Posts from 4 Unique Categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695183/how-to-create-a-wordpress-homepage-slider-with-multiple-queries-for-most-recent)) and that does not answer this question.  So I'm asking again..

Is there a Wordpress slider option that will display the "Featured Image" from new posts, and that can be added to a theme either as a widget or not?

Thanks to all in advance...

Comment: You want a plugin that does that or write the code yourself?

Comment: to your question: YES. However, how to do it will totally depend on your approach, slider script, etc

Comment: Would be nice to find a plugin.  However, if there is a script base that's available, that would be great as well.  Can't seem to find a plug-in that does this.

Comment: @Fabio I would like to simply replace the current banner slider that's on the theme with one that pulls the last "X" number of posts and display their featured image, along with linking to those posts.

Comment: @LeeFuller: u can try these plugins:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/islidex/

and



http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-parallax-content-slider/